# Heroku local: how to install support for Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, pdo

I am using `heroku local` to try and develop in PHP locally before pushing to heroku.

However, I am not able to use Postgres locally because the PDO driver is missing:

- Getting a `'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'` error message
- And, indeed, `phpinfo()` reveals that `pdo_pgsql` is not installed.

**How can I install (or enable?) PostgreSQL PDO (pdo_pgsql) on `heroku local` ?**

I could not find anything in the official docs, nor online. (The docs seem to be lacking for PHP and, especially, on how to use heroku locally.)

FYI, running Mac OS X.

---

If needed, here's the minimal example I'm working with for testing purposes:

```
/**
 * postgres-helloworld.php
 * Runs fine on XAMPP, which has PHP Version 5.5.15 with pdo_pgsql installed.
 * But won't run on heroku local, which has PHP Version 5.5.34 WITHOUT pdo_pgsql installed.
 *  `PDOException`, `could not find driver'`
 */
$dbh = new PDO( "pgsql:dbname=test;host=localhost", 'fabien', NULL );
$res = $dbh->query(  'SELECT name FROM test_table'  )->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
echo $res[0]['name']; // echoes the content of said table, i.e. `hello database` -- OK

?>
```

---

EDIT:

I realized my whole model of what `heroku local` does was totally off. It merely does this:

> “Heroku Local reads configuration variables from a .env file.” (from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local)

I'd *wrongly assumed* it provided, locally, the same sort of flexibility heroku provides in the cloud (i.e.: [dev-prod-parity](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity), e.g.: the ability to pick which PHP version to run and reproduce locally the same setup as in the cloud), and that it came with its own binaries.

In reality, `heroku local` merely relies on the system's default PHP install and extensions (or lack thereof) for running the web server.

Once understood, the problem became to fix it by installing pdo_pgsql on the local system, as per Shyam Bhimani's solution.

Comment: Did you try this ? https://www.sitepoint.com/hosted-postgresql-with-heroku/
Or you can do it locally, If you can tell me which OS you are using I can try to help you out.

Comment: @ShyamBhimani I'm able to provision a database for my heroku app hosted on heroku. I was also able to create a database on my local development environment (Mac OS X.) The issue is how do I install pdo_pgsql locally for heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ./configure --with-pdo-pgsql
```

Use **--with-pdo-pgsql[=DIR]** to install PDO PostgreSQL extension, where the optional [=DIR] is the PostgreSQL base install directory, or the path to pg_config.

for more detail you can follow this two documents [**(1)**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php) [**(2)**](https://gist.github.com/doole/8651341)

Comment: Thank you, that `install_psql_php.sh` script you reference on link #2 helped a lot. I also realized my whole mode of just what `heroku local` does was off and will update my original question if that may help someone.